# Is there a faster pythonic way of incrementing part of an array?

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, numpy

I have an array of the form (just an example):

```
array([[ 14.,  48.],
       [ 18.,  45.],
       [  9.,  42.],
       [  9.,  57.],
       [  3.,  30.]])
```

And I want to increment by 1 the first component of all the elements to get this:

```
array([[ 15.,  48.],
       [ 19.,  45.],
       [ 10.,  42.],
       [ 10.,  57.],
       [  4.,  30.]])
```

Right now, I am using this to do so:

```
arr = np.array([arr.T[0] + 1, arr.T[1]]).T
```

But I was wondering if there was a better way to manipulate subarrays like this. Is there?

Comment: It looks like you want to represent matrices. Consider numpy; you could then use matirx arithmetic to do just that.

Comment: @Marcin numpy is in the tags, and `np.array` in the code. i think we can safely assume he is already using numpy.

Comment: @Marcin He's already using `numpy`.

Comment: @M4rtini It wasn't when I made my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
arr = array([[ 14.,  48.],
   [ 18.,  45.],
   [  9.,  42.],
   [  9.,  57.],
   [  3.,  30.]])
arr[:,0] += 1
```

if you need a copy, copy the array first with `arr.copy()`.